# Javascript regular expression quantifiers: what does it mean to match zero or more times

Tags: javascript, regex, quantifiers

So I am just trying to clarify what exactly the * quantifier in a javascript regular expression does. The definition from MDN states the following:

x* Matches the preceding item "x" 0 or more times. For example, /bo*/ matches "boooo" in "A ghost booooed" and "b" in "A bird warbled", but nothing in "A goat grunted".

My understanding of this definition is that it will match a "b", and it will match a "b" followed by any number of "o" characters. So would the fact that it matches a "b" character not constitute as 1 match instead of 0? I guess it is the "0 or more times" statement that is throwing me off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important phrase in there is "**the preceding item**". If the preceeding item is a single character, like here, that means that *that* character can be repeated 0 or more times. `bo*` will match a `b`, followed by zero or more `o`s. `o*` alone will match zero or more `o`s. `b(?:oo)*` will match `b`, or `boo`, or `boooo`, etc. (zero, or two, or four, or six, ... `o`s)

Look at the token that immediately precedes the quantifier to see what it's quantifying.

For another example, `[ab][xy]*` will match `a`, or `b`, or `ax`, or `axxxy`, or `byxyy`. The token preceding the quantifier, `[xy]`, which matches either an `x` or a `y`, gets repeated zero or more times.

Comment: Ok so I think I have a better understanding now based on what you stated about "that character being REPEATED 0 or more times." So in the case of "b" followed by a character other that "o", it is the fact that "b" is not repeated, so that constitutes "zero or more times"...correct?

Comment: WIth `bo*`, the token immediately preceding the `*` quantifier is the `o`, while the `b` matches normally, and then the `o` gets repeated 0 or more times.